# Why Does the Reverse Flash Vibrate?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

In *Flash*, every time we see the man-in-yellow, he's always vibrating constantly. Like this:

[image: Reverse Flash]

Admittedly, it looks super scary and ominious, but what's the logical reasoning for why Eobard Thawne chooses to vibrate?

And why do his eyes turn red? Barry's didn't do that when *he* vibrated his face, but every time Eobard dons his mask, it lights up...

**Note:** I'm referring to DC's Flash series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eobard Thawne chooses to vibrate for exactly the reasons you just said: to look scary and ominous. Additionally, he also does it in order to **mask his identity**- which Barry himself also does when he talks to Iris in his alter-ego. The red eyes also are just for show, and are there only just to make him look scary. His suit actually has red lights near his eyes in order to create that effect.

Comment: Actually, the reason his eyes are red is something else. They are red because he doesn't utilize the speedforce, but another power source: the negative speed force. This is elaborated in the season 5 when XS learns it from him

Comment: The reason his eye glows is the negative speed force. Anger in a lot of movies makes people's eyes go red.